# Упаковка компонента и перенос на другой сайт

Tags: modx, php

Добрый день! У меня к вам гуру вопросы такие на сегодня. Я написал свой компонент на modx и хотел бы его перенести на другой сайт тоже на modx. Даст ли эффект простое копирование нужных папок в access и в ядре (core) + копирование данных из базы? Или надо делать еще какие-то манипуляции для успешного переноса компонента? И второй вопрос: как можно написанный в modx компонент упаковать в инсталляционный архив?

На сайте https://bezumkin.ru бесплатного по этой теме мало очень, почти все погружено в платные уроки, так что халявы тут нет). Ищу знающих людей, кто может помочь в этом деле.

Спасибо, за внимание к моему тикету.

Answer (score 1):

Есть же Яндекс, Google, Bing, Yahoo и т.д. В каждой из этих компаний сидят сотни программистов и стремятся сделать так, чтобы на вопросы люди сразу могли находить ответы. Надо только правильно спросить. Вот здесь http://habrahabr.ru/post/126635/, например, в конце приведена ссылка на скачивание пакета, готового к установке. Скачай и посмотри как там все сделано и какие файлы в него включены. Вот здесь http://habrahabr.ru/post/127722/ еще информация. Читай - не хочу.

Comment: Насчет первой ссылки, урок, видимо, не в полной мере оформлен, потому что следуя инструкциям я получил невалидный компонент. Болванка далека от совершенства. Что касается второй ссылки, то тоже мимо, на данном этапе мне надо просто упаковать компонент (Свой или сторонний). Читал что для этого надо использовать modExtra. Плюс в кратком видео находил, что используя git клонировался репозиторий, а затем упаковывался компонент, используя вышеуказанный инсталлятор modExtra. Вот в этом направлении хотел услышать ответы или почитать как это делать. К сожалению по этой теме мало материала...